# Need Firebase Database behaviour clarification when inside a Service

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am testing a feature which requires a Firebase database write to happen at midnight everyday. Now it is possible that at this particular time, the client app might not be connected to the internet.

I have been using Firebase with persistence off as that can potentially cause issues of stale data in another feature of mine.

From my observation, if I disconnect the app before the write and keep it this way for a minute or so, Firebase eventually reconnects when I turn on the connectivity again and performs the write.

My main questions are:

- Will this behaviour be consistent even if the connectivity is lost for quite a few hours?
- Will Firebase timeout?

Since it is inside a forever running service, does it still need persistence to ensure that writes are not lost? (assume that the service does not restart).

If the service does restart, will the writes get lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some experience with this exact case, and I actually do NOT recommend the use of a background service for managing your Firebase requests. In fact, I wouldn't recommend managing Firebase requests at all (explained later).

Services, even though we can make them run forever, tend to get killed by the system quite a lot actually (unless you set their CPU priority to a higher level, but even then the system still might kill them).

If you call a Firebase Write call (of any kind), and your service gets killed, the write will get lost as you said. Unless, you create a sophisticated manager in which you store requests that haven't been committed into your internal storage, and load them up each time the service is restarted - but that is a very dirty work to do, considering the fact that Firebase Developers took care of us and made `.setPersistenceEnabled(true)` :)

I know, you mentioned you don't want to use it, but I STRONGLY advise you to do so. It works like charm, no services required, and you don't have to worry at all about managing your write requests. Perhaps it would be better to solve the other issue you have in order to make this possible.

To sum up, here's what I would do in your case:

1. I would call the `.setPersistenceEnabled(true)` someplace at the beginning (extending the `Application` class and calling it from `onCreate()` is recommended)
2. I would use Android's [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and register a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive an alarm at midnight (repetitive or not - you decide)
3. Inside the BroadcastReceiver, I'd simply call a write function of Firebase and worry about nothing :)

To make sure I covered all of your questions:

1. > will this behaviour be consistent....

No. Case-scenario: Midnight time, your service has successfully received the call and is now trying to write into Firebase. If, for example, the user has no connection until 6 AM (just a case scenario), there is a very high chance that the system will kill it during those 6 hours, and your write will get lost. Flight Time, or staying in an area with no internet coverage - both are examples of risky scenarios that could break your app's consistency

2. > Will Firebase Timeout?

It definitely could, as mentioned. I wouldn't take the risk and make a 80-90% working app. Use persistence and have a 100% working app :)

I believe I covered the rest of the questions..

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you... I'll check it out.... Hopefully i can handle the other issue then lol :) i actually was thinking about implementing the sophisticated system you were talking about lol :'D

Comment: I also had this query in my mind and the way you have explained is commendable. Thanks.